# Merge 2 XML files in XSTL1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, merge, xslt-1.0

I'm looking for a way to merge 2 XML documents
- if they have the same attributes 
- take the elements from the 1st document, but if the elements match, take the value from the 2nd document.

I can get all the elements from the 1st or from the 2nd, but I am unable to merge.

This is what i've tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ds="http://www.test.com/xmlns/application" >

    <xsl:param name="ADAPTER" select="'merge'"/>

    <xsl:variable name="GLOBALS" select="document(concat($ADAPTER,'.xml'))"/>

    <xsl:template match="*|/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="//ds:binding">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$GLOBALS//ds:binding[@name=current()/@name]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$GLOBALS//ds:binding[@name=current()/@name]"/>                        
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>                       
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here are the input.xml the merge.xml and the output.xml, to make myself more clear.

input.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://www.test.com/xmlns/application" name="test">
    <services>
        <service name="service1">
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <bindings>
                <binding name="binding1">
                    <machine>machine1</machine>
                    <product>
                        <type>type1</type>
                        <version>2.0</version>
                        <location>c:/somefolder/1</location>
                    </product>
                    <contact>me</contact>
                    <setting>
                        <startOnBoot>false</startOnBoot>
                        <enableVerbose>false</enableVerbose>
                        <maxLogFileSize>50</maxLogFileSize>
                        <maxLogFileCount>8</maxLogFileCount>
                        <threadCount>1</threadCount>
                        <NTService>
                            <runAsNT>false</runAsNT>
                            <startupType>automatic</startupType>
                        </NTService>
                        <java>
                            <initHeapSize>32</initHeapSize>
                            <maxHeapSize>256</maxHeapSize>
                            <threadStackSize>256</threadStackSize>
                        </java>
                    </setting>
                    <shutdown>
                        <checkpoint>true</checkpoint>
                        <timeout>0</timeout>
                    </shutdown>
                </binding>
            </bindings>
        </service>
        <service name="service2">
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <bindings>
                <binding name="binding2">
                    <machine>machine2</machine>
                    <product>
                        <type>type2</type>
                        <version>2.1.1.7</version>
                        <location>d:/otherfolder</location>
                    </product>
                    <contact>you</contact>
                    <setting>
                        <startOnBoot>false</startOnBoot>
                        <enableVerbose>false</enableVerbose>
                        <maxLogFileSize>20000</maxLogFileSize>
                        <maxLogFileCount>5</maxLogFileCount>
                        <threadCount>8</threadCount>
                        <NTService>
                            <runAsNT>false</runAsNT>
                            <startupType>automatic</startupType>
                        </NTService>
                        <java>
                            <initHeapSize>32</initHeapSize>
                            <maxHeapSize>256</maxHeapSize>
                            <threadStackSize>256</threadStackSize>
                        </java>
                    </setting>
                    <shutdown>
                        <checkpoint>true</checkpoint>
                        <timeout>5</timeout>
                    </shutdown>
                </binding>
            </bindings>
        </service>
    </services>
</application>
```

merge.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://www.test.com/xmlns/application" name="test">
    <services>

        <service name="service2">
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <bindings>
                <binding name="binding2">
                    <setting>
                        <startOnBoot>true</startOnBoot>
                    </setting>
                    <shutdown>
                        <timeout>7</timeout>
                    </shutdown>
                </binding>
            </bindings>
        </service>
        <service name="service1">
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <bindings>
                <binding name="binding1">
                    <product>
                        <type>custom</type>
                    </product>
                    <contact>someoneelse</contact>
                    <setting>
                        <threadCount>10</threadCount>
                        <NTService>
                            <runAsNT>true</runAsNT>
                        </NTService>
                        <java>
                            <initHeapSize>64</initHeapSize>
                            <maxHeapSize>1024</maxHeapSize>
                        </java>
                    </setting>
                </binding>
            </bindings>
        </service>
    </services>
</application>
```

output.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://www.test.com/xmlns/application" name="test">
    <services>
        <service name="service1">
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <bindings>
                <binding name="binding1">
                    <machine>machine1</machine>
                    <product>
                        <type>custom</type>
                        <version>2.0</version>
                        <location>c:/somefolder/1</location>
                    </product>
                    <contact>someoneelse</contact>
                    <setting>
                        <startOnBoot>false</startOnBoot>
                        <enableVerbose>false</enableVerbose>
                        <maxLogFileSize>50</maxLogFileSize>
                        <maxLogFileCount>8</maxLogFileCount>
                        <threadCount>10</threadCount>
                        <NTService>
                            <runAsNT>true</runAsNT>
                            <startupType>automatic</startupType>
                        </NTService>
                        <java>
                            <initHeapSize>64</initHeapSize>
                            <maxHeapSize>1024</maxHeapSize>
                            <threadStackSize>256</threadStackSize>
                        </java>
                    </setting>
                    <shutdown>
                        <checkpoint>true</checkpoint>
                        <timeout>0</timeout>
                    </shutdown>
                </binding>
            </bindings>
        </service>
        <service name="service2">
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <bindings>
                <binding name="binding1">
                    <machine>machine2</machine>
                    <product>
                        <type>type2</type>
                        <version>2.1.1.7</version>
                        <location>d:/otherfolder</location>
                    </product>
                    <contact>you</contact>
                    <setting>
                        <startOnBoot>true</startOnBoot>
                        <enableVerbose>false</enableVerbose>
                        <maxLogFileSize>20000</maxLogFileSize>
                        <maxLogFileCount>5</maxLogFileCount>
                        <threadCount>8</threadCount>
                        <NTService>
                            <runAsNT>false</runAsNT>
                            <startupType>automatic</startupType>
                        </NTService>
                        <java>
                            <initHeapSize>32</initHeapSize>
                            <maxHeapSize>256</maxHeapSize>
                            <threadStackSize>256</threadStackSize>
                        </java>
                    </setting>
                    <shutdown>
                        <checkpoint>true</checkpoint>
                        <timeout>7</timeout>
                    </shutdown>
                </binding>
            </bindings>
        </service>
    </services>
</application>
```

Comment: Have you already tried something?

Comment: i've tried this, this copies or the 1st or the 2nd: <xsl:template match="//binding">
  <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="$GLOBALS//ds:binding[@name=current()/@name]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$GLOBALS//ds:binding[@name=current()/@name]"/>      
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>      
   </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

Comment: Please add it to your post, and ensure it is usable... (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Thank you.

Comment: done, i've stripped it from the bigger xsl (it is only for binding and below [an other problem]) :-)

Comment: Made the binding unique so my example works.

Comment: The XML documents have elements in a namespace, the XSLT does not take that into account at all.

Comment: Sorry, will restore it as it is and test it, will update asap

Comment: Ok, now it technically working

Comment: Can anyone help me a bit further? Thanks in advance!